# Twisted http client using client certificate

Tags: python, ssl, twisted

I'm trying to write a twisted https client, that uses a client certificate for authentication. This is the example from the twisted docs for making a simple https request:

```
from __future__ import print_function

from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web.client import Agent
from twisted.web.http_headers import Headers

agent = Agent(reactor)

d = agent.request(
    b'GET',
    b'https://127.0.0.1:8880/test',
    Headers({'User-Agent': ['Twisted Web Client Example']}),
    None)

def cbResponse(ignored):
    print('Response received')
d.addCallback(cbResponse)

def cbShutdown(ignored):
    reactor.stop()
d.addBoth(cbShutdown)

reactor.run()
```

I've found [this](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/ssl.html#client-with-certificates) explanation on how to use a client with ssl certificates. I have no idea though, how I can tell the agent to use a certificate for authentication. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct `Agent` with an `IPolicyForHTTPS` which can create a `contextFactory` to provide a client certificate to the TLS connection.

```
certData = getModule(__name__).filePath.sibling('public.pem').getContent()
authData = getModule(__name__).filePath.sibling('server.pem').getContent()
clientCertificate = ssl.PrivateCertificate.loadPEM(authData)
authority = ssl.Certificate.loadPEM(certData)
options = ssl.optionsForClientTLS(u'example.com', authority,
                                  clientCertificate)

class SinglePolicy(object):
    def creatorForNetloc(self, hostname, port):
        return options

agent = Agent(reactor, SinglePolicy())
```

Comment: When I try that, I get the following error message: AttributeError: 'ClientTLSOptions' object has no attribute 'getContext'. I tried this before and it seemed to me that passing ClientTLSOptions to the Agent won't work.

Comment: What version of Twisted do you have?

Comment: Ah I left out a layer... updating answer.

Comment: Now I got it. Had to add @implementer(IPolicyForHTTPS) to SinglePolicy tough. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: How to pass server.key here?